# Pandas - formatting time and removing trailing zeros

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column `Time` which looks like this:

`[df]`

```
Date              Time  
0  2017-02-05  00:00:02.0000000  
1  2017-02-05  00:00:04.0000000
```

I wish to convert a date_time type.

The trailing decimal is always `0` and thus, can be removed.

`df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'],format='%H:%M:%S')`

However, this returns:

`ValueError: unconverted data remains: .0000000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier is add `.%f`:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'],format='%H:%M:%S.%f')
print (df)
         Date                Time
0  2017-02-05 1900-01-01 00:00:02
1  2017-02-05 1900-01-01 00:00:04
```

Another solution with split:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'].str.split('.').str[0],format='%H:%M:%S')
print (df)
         Date                Time
0  2017-02-05 1900-01-01 00:00:02
1  2017-02-05 1900-01-01 00:00:04
```

Comment: Using `.%f` is a tad faster ;) Thanks!

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck! Nice day!